# Control Arduino using Express JS server and Johnny-Five

Tags: reactjs, express, arduino, johnny-five

I want to control my Arduino from a web interface, so I've created the client side in ReactJS and the server side in ExpressJS (Johnny-Five included).

I just want to update the interval of a blinking led in real time, based on the user input. Here is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const five = require('johnny-five');

const app = express();
const board = new five.Board();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

board.on('ready', function () {
  app.post("/api/led-flash", function (req, res) {
    let led = new five.Led(13);
    led.blink(req.body.interval);
  });
});

app.listen("5000", () => {
  console.log("App listening on port 5000");
});
```

The code seems to work only for a few requests at the beginning.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to start the server **after** the board is ready. So something like the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const five = require('johnny-five');

const app = express();
const board = new five.Board();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/led-flash", function (req, res) {
    // perform some initial cleanup work if needed like resetting LEDs.
    // ...


    let led = new five.Led(13);
    led.blink(req.body.interval);

    res.json({ message: 'success!'})

    // Some additional work after success
    // ...
});

function startServer() {
    app.listen("5000", () => {
        console.log("App listening on port 5000");
    });
}

board.on('ready', startServer);
```

The above is untested, but post a solution if you find one!

Comment: Good point! Though, it seems that the previous blinking values are not ignored. It just looks like the new interval values are added on the "stack".

Comment: You'll probably want to do some "cleanup" _before_ and _after_ execution.

Comment: The problem was that my requests never ended, by using res.end() or res.json() etc. Thank you very much for your help.